# How to enable a button to clicked multiple times in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, button

I want a button to be clicked. Every time it is clicked a label is changed. My main part of code looks like this:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" autopostback="false"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />

</div>
</form>
```

The code behind is this:

```
    private int n;
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        n++;
        Label1.Text = n.ToString();
    }
```

But I can only click it once. In the next times the number does not change. What should I do?

Comment: You need to store 'n' in view state so the value is retained through multiple postbacks.  Easiest way to do this is make it a property: http://www.karpach.com/property-in-viewstate.htm

Comment: I'd consider using JavaScript for this. Do you really need to POST back to the server with every click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try another method..Create an **input hidden field** and set its value as 0..

```
<input id="Hidden1" type="hidden" runat="server" value="0"/>
```

**Code behind**:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = Hidden1.Value;
        Hidden1.Value = (Convert.ToInt32(Hidden1.Value) + 1).ToString();
    }
```